# How to avoid a "Nested transactions are not supported." error?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, entity-framework

I am using `EF6` to do some pretty simple integration with a `MySql` database.

The `Nested transactions are not supported.` error occurs after I do the following:

1. Attempt to add a `key` that already exists... Which leads to the error: `Duplicate entry 'asdf' for key 'UserName_UNIQUE'`
2. Attempt to add anything afterwards... Which leads to the error: `Nested transactions are not supported.`

I guess I'm not sure what would be `Nested` about these two queries...  What am I doing wrong:

**And for some code**

```
using (var db = C2SCore.BuildDatabaseContext())
{
  db.Users.Add(new UserProfile { UserName = UserName, Password = Password });
  db.SaveChanges(); // <- Errors occur here...
}
```

This snippet runs (as my the flow described above implies) for every `UserProfile` I add.

Comment: Where is the duplicate `key` code?

Comment: @rae1 The `UserName` is the `key`... If that's what you're asking.

Comment: What happens if explicitly opening up a wrapping TransactionScope? And there isn't a context open from *elsewhere*, is there?

Comment: Where does the duplicate `key` error occurs and where does the "Nested transactions ..." error occurs?

Comment: @rae1 They both occur at the `db.SaveChanges()`

Comment: @user2864740 I don't have the `TransactionScope` class available to me... Do you have to do something special to get it?

Comment: @Andrew See [TransactionScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope(v=vs.110).aspx) (it is from System.Transactions); with an ambient TS present I believe all the EF operations will use it (and if it is aborted it can't be subsequently used). However, this sort of error normally comes when using a *deferred* LINQ/fetch operation - which is why I wonder if there is another context (that is indirectly accessible) lurking about.

Comment: I have the exactly the same problem. However, they are aware of it: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=71502

Comment: I've got this problem too.  Any solution!?  Seems like this Mysql/C# stuff is a duff!

Answer (score 6):

I have exactly the same problem.
Try the following workaround by wrapping it into a TransactionScope:

```
using System.Transactions; // Add assembly in references

using (var db = C2SCore.BuildDatabaseContext())
{
  using (var tran = new TransactionScope())
  {
    db.Users.Add(new UserProfile { UserName = UserName, Password = Password });
    db.SaveChanges(); // <- Should work now after first exception
    tran.Complete();
  }
}

<package id="MySql.Data" version="6.8.3" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="MySql.Data.Entities" version="6.8.3.0" targetFramework="net45" />
```

However, they are aware of it: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=71502

Comment: This is the only workaround for this I found, thanks. It does require a lot of changes to your code however as every operation with a `DbContext.SaveChanges()` has to be wrapped in a `TransactionScope`. Could be useful if your app just has a few of those though.

Comment: Correction: that doesn't work for me. The exception doesn't happen, but the data isn't saved to the database.

Answer (score 3):

Please I just want to reiterate **"they are aware of it"** but without people signing up and bumping the thread it is likely going to take longer to resolve when this is an urgent issue.

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=71502

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a `db.Connection.Open()` at the start and `db.Connection.Close()` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing how it is now 2017 and this issue still exists I am going to post the only workaround I have been able to find that does not involve pulling the source code. Adding ConnectionReset=True to the connection string will resolve the issue. It should be noted this will incur an additional round trip to the database for every connection used in the connection pool.

Here is an example:   `server=localhost;port=3306;database=somedatabase;uid=someuser;password=itsasecret;ConnectionReset=True;`

Answer (score 0):

The error then indicates you need to dispose of the transaction once the first error arises, before you can continue with other operations. I would suggest placing a `try ... catch` and disposing of the current transaction in the `finally` block.

You might even have to dispose of the current `Connection`, but I would try dealing with the transactions first.

Comment: There is a `using` around the context object and the code provided does not indicate any context leakage.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting my answer here since this thread is the first result when googling "entity framework nested transactions are not supported", hopefully it will help someone:

For me, this issue appeared while trying to save illegal characters (hebrew characters) in a MySQL DB, longtext field

Answer (score 0):

In my case, client application with Entity Framework, can't connect to MySql database that hosted on server over Internet. Problem solved after remove `proxy` from internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error with Oracle's MySQL.Data provider version 6.7.9.

The database had the autocommit feature turned off and it was necessary to use a transaction before saving changes from a DataSet (call to DataAdapter.Update) - It was not necessary for another database using the same schema but with the autocommit turned on.

Using a transaction just for saving worked with DevArt's dotConnect.Express.for.MySQL driver (version 8.16.1541) but not with Oracle's driver.

It looks like with Oracle's driver, accessing the DB even for a select creates some kind of default transaction.

So I could finally work with Oracle's driver after using a transaction for every read access to the DB (DataAdapter.Fill).